# Control if diagonal swipe is for horizontal UIScrollView or nested vertical UIScrollView?

Tags: uiscrollview, ios6, nested, swipe, diagonal

#### Short

How can I control wether or not a swipe on a UIScrollView has made a big enough Y delta to be considered a vertical swipe and let it be handled by a nested UIScrollView (UIWebView)?

#### Long

I have a UIScrollView which pages horizontally. A ‘page’ is a UIWebView (which contains a UIScrollView) and only scrolls vertically. The content sizes are all properly set so that this works as expected.

However, I’ve noticed that when you try to swipe horizontally fast, you have a high chance of making a slightly diagonal swipe. If it’s only a tiny bit, the scrollviews handle it as I would like to, but every now and then the Y delta is enough to make the nested scrollview (UIWebView) recognise the swipe as a vertical one, whereas the X delta could be considered big enough to indicate a horizontal swipe.

I have found a lot of old articles that explain that one should override the standard UIResponder touch methods (e.g. `touchesBegan:withEvent:`), however, nowadays this is all handled by gesture recognisers.

So how can I influence the paging scrollview’s pan gesture recogniser to allow more Y delta for a horizontal swipe?

One way to make it work, as I need, is by:

- setting `delaysContentTouches` on the paging scrollview to `NO`
- to the nested scrollviews’ pan gesture recognisers add a dependency on the paging scrollview’s pan gesture recogniser to fail.

However, this breaks vertical scrolling in the nested scrollviews in such a way that they are not recognised until the swipe has ended and done fast. I suspect this is because the paging scrollview’s pan gesture recogniser doesn’t fail until the touches end.